# Determine the "ECDSA key fingerprint" of a Windows 10 Host

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh

When setting up SSH capability between two Linux machines, I am faced with:

```
The authenticity of host 'x.x.x.x (y.y.y.y)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I use the following command (in the subject host (server)) to verify said fingerprint is the correct one:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

However, when setting up SSH capability from a Linux SSH client to a Windows 10 SSH server, when faced with the same challenge, how do I pull said ECDSA key fingerprint from said Windows 10 SSH server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 10 SSH server is also OpenSSH and includes the same commands. It stores the host keys in `C:\ProgramData\ssh`.

```
ssh-keygen -lf C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

```
ssh-keyscan localhost | ssh-keygen -lf -
```

Third-party SSH servers might have their own commands, e.g. Bitvise WinSSHD has a graphical interface for host key management, but `ssh-keyscan` would work with those as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am using an old version of SSH (6.7) . In order to get the ECDSA key fingerprint in the same format as shown in the OP, the following command, run with Admin privileges on the Windows 10 host, is required:

```
ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

I was able to cobble together this command thanks to info I received from user1686

**UPDATE:** FYI, the information above was valid for **Debian Jesse** on the Linux client (with the server being a Windows 10 machine).

Under **Debian Stretch**:

On said Linux client:

```
~$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u8, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019
```

On said Windows 10 server (command line):

```
C:\Users\booboo>ssh -V
OpenSSH_9.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1v  1 Aug 2023
```

In this case, in order to get the ECDSA key fingerprint in the desired format, the following command, run with Admin privileges on the Windows 10 host, is required:

```
ssh-keygen -lf C:/cygwin64/etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

I have no idea why the version of the **ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub** file in the **cygwin64** folder must be used (vice the version that resides in the **ProgramData** folder, as was previously called under **Debian Jesse**).