# Which ECDSA Public Key in a Windows 10 OpenSSH Server Will Be Used?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, openssh

Linux OpenSSH client (**Debian Stretch**, **OpenSSH version 7.4p1**)

Windows 10 OpenSSH server (**OpenSSH version 9.4p1**)

Said Windows 10 OpenSSH server has two different ECDSA public key files loaded on its hard drive:

**C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub** , and

**C:/cygwin64/etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub**

I first loaded Cygwin on said Windows 10 server over two years ago. After setting up the SSH "bridge" with said Linux client, things went smoothly during that time, even after a distribution upgrade from **Debian Jessie** to **Debian Stretch** on said Linux client.

Last week, I updated OpenSSH on said Linux client. Right about that time, I also noticed that the IP assigned to said Windows 10 server had changed (I don't know if said IP change was related to said OpenSSH update). During this thrash, I also updated said Windows 10 server's OpenSSH version via a Cygwin update.

Yesterday, when attempting to SSH from said Linux client to said Windows 10 server (for the first time since the abovementioned recent changes), I got the following message:

```
The authenticity of host 'xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx)' can't be established
ECDSA key fingerprint is xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

When investigating the ECDSA public key loaded on said Windows 10 server (to verify a match with the above message), I discovered that the public key loaded in said server's **...ProgramData** folder, which had been used by said Linux client for over two years, was no longer being accessed by said Linux client. Instead, said Linux client was wanting to access said server's ECDSA public key that resides in said server's **...cygwin64** folder!

FYI, on said Windows 10 server, the **C:\cygwin\var\log\sshd.log** file is blank and the **C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs\** folder is empty.

**What is going on here?**

**Is there any way I can dictate which of said Windows 10 server's two ECDSA public keys will be "used" by said Linux client?**

**(UPDATE: Please disregard the following question, as said native OpenSSH scheme is NOT loaded on said Windows 10 server, as seen by the discussion in the comments, below)** In particular, what can I do to "force" the use of the OpenSSH scheme native to Windows 10 (vice the Cygwin scheme currently in use)?

FYI, these questions initially arose due to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1631408/determine-the-ecdsa-key-fingerprint-of-a-windows-10-host) I made earlier (in particular, check out my answer).

***FINAL UPDATE:***

It turns out that the Windows 10 server did not have the [Windows native OpenSSH service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui) loaded. I decided to keep said server in its current state, with the extant OpenSSH service being **CYGWIN sshd**.
I really only SSH into said server once about every two weeks, and that only for a **Unison** sync. Although the updates would be easier to handle if said native Windows OpenSSH service were being used, I've just subscribed to the cywgin email update service and will update OpenSSH on said Windows machine whenever I see such an updated version become available...

Comment: Unless you pointed the OpenSSH Server to your cygwin64 folder it absolutely WOULD NOT look there by default, since cygwin64 is not required or necessary for OpenSSH capability on Windows.  " I also updated said Windows 10 server's OpenSSH version via a Cygwin update." - This means you are running OpenSSH within Cygwin and are NOT using the default capability within Windows.  Of course verbose logs from the OpenSSH Server would explain exactly what was happening.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your input! I know very little about Windows. How would I "point" the server to the cygwin64 folder? I will update my question to include info about any pertinent logs.

Comment: Either the OpenSSH Server is the version the comes with the current version of Windows or you’re erroneously running the version within Cygwin. The verbose server logs would tell you everything you need to provide the critical information required to answer your question

Comment: `sshd` [server] and `ssh` [client] don't search for SSH keys - they have to be told where to look via the [`sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) or [`ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) _(if using PuTTY/other client, via its respective settings)_. The message displayed occurs when the fingerprint doesn't exist in `known_hosts`, so if the Cygwin key was used, at some point it had to have been copied. or symlinked, to the user's default `.ssh` directory or have been specified within the `sshd_config` or `ssh_config`.

Comment: In light of the above comments, I have added a third question to the OP.

Comment: I think you should figure out / recall how does your ssh server daemon get started (service? start-up bat whatsoever?), then in turn you figure out which version you are using and whether that version is the one *you want to use*. (Hopefully only one "thing" has been attempting to start either of them.) At that point you might also want to investigate whether the PATH environment variable has led to the unwanted version being started, if that "thing" does not use a full path to run the sshd executable.

Comment: Modified sshd_config seems to be the least likely case, but double checking the one *corresponds* to the wanted / running sshd executable is probably the last thing to check. (Btw, it has nothing to do with the client or in turn, any ssh_config, since the client doesn't get to decide which key does the server use.)

Comment: Btw, IIRC, it is possible to figure out which exact executable is a process in Task Manager.

Comment: I've a feeling that the (presumably Windows-based) OpenSSH service in the server was "replaced" by the Cygwin update I did (which included OpenSSH). I DO see the **CYGWIN sshd** service running in the Windows Services GUI window. Things are currently working for me...is there a compelling reason I should stop using said Cygwin service and, instead, ensure that the Windows-based SSH daemon runs in its place?

Comment: `In particular, what can I do to "force" the use of the OpenSSH scheme native to Windows 10` It has been unclear to me what exactly you want. It seems that you do not like the fact that the key is under the cygwin etc path. On the other hand, I would say native build is preferred over cygwin build in general unless the native build has caveats / is bugged, since the posix compat layer of cygwin normally leads to slower performance.

Comment: @TomYan That is correct - I'd prefer to use the native build, primarily since I seldom get in there to update Cygwin. My plan is to remove the Cygwin version of OpenSSH.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148026/discussion-between-digger-and-tom-yan).